# Get Google query search keyword

Tags: php, javascript

i publish below code for get referer link from my user and save to my site .
i want get google keyword search like

```
http://google.com/?q=design
```

but this code only back

```
http://google.com/?sa=t
```

for all search

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var e = document.createElement("script");
e.src = "http//mysite.com/c.php?token=12948&referrer="+document.referrer;
e.type="text/javascript";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e);
</script>
```

i cant use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] because this code use for weblog too . 
any can help me???

Comment: Do u want to know the impact of keywords on your site or use it for other stuff ? If its the impact u are after try [Google webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/)

Comment: like stat or counter site . i want publish this code for user i they put this in header and i capture search keyword from google

Answer (score 1):

It won't help you much because many google searches are now over ssl where you won't get a referrer

Comment: i want for regural search no ssl search. and how stat can capture keyword with this eternal js code?